# Firebase me dice que hay 19k peticiones pero no es cierto, o si?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, requests

[image: peticiones de firebase]

Firebase me dice que hay 19k, pero solo cargue una vez la página que contiene un sencillo blog.
Envío parte de mi código que genera el blog, he probado dejar 2 días sin usar y no aparece ninguna requests en la tab uso de firebase, pero accesar mi url del blog 1 sola vez aparecen 19k?.
Por lo que entendí, si el blog tiene 10 entradas, pues contaran 10 requests, hasta ahí no hay problema, puedo cachearlo de algún modo en el frontend, pero 19k no me hace sentido alguno, pensé tal vez que por un redireccionamiento ssl, pero no hay tal cosa, no sé si UseEffect tiene la capacidad de hacer eso, pero en tal caso solo cada vez que es renderizado el componente, no veo por donde me está haciendo esas peticiones. Gracias de antemano.

Articles.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from '../../firebase-config';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"




function Articles() {


    const ArticleCard = props => {
        // console.log(props);
        const { articleData, index } = props;
        const { title, date, content, picture } = articleData
    
        return (
            <article className="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 p-4" key={index}>
    
                <div className="card-content">
                    <div className="card-image">
                        <img src={picture} alt={title} />
                    </div>
                    <h2 className="card-title text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{title}</h2>
                    <p className="card-subtitle text-gray-600 mb-2">{date}</p>
                    <p className="card-text">{content}</p>
                </div>
    
            </article >
        )
    }
    
    const [blogArticles, setBlogArticles] = useState([
    /*{
    title: "Lorem 1",
    date: "date 1",
    content: "lorem pixel",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/536/354"
  }, {
    title: "Lorem 2", date: "date 1",

    content: "lorem pixel",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/536/354"
  }, {
    title: "Lorem 3", date: "date 1",

    content: "lorem pixel",
    picture: "https://picsum.photos/536/354"
  }*/]);

    const articlesCollectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');


    useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(articlesCollectionRef);
            setBlogArticles(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        };

        getPosts();
    }, [articlesCollectionRef]);

    return (

        <div className = "container mx-auto p-4" >
            <header className="text-center">
                <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">Posts</h1>
            </header>
            <main className="flex flex-wrap">


                {
                    blogArticles.map((article, index) =>
                        <ArticleCard key={index} articleData={article} index={index} />)
                }

            </main>
        </div>

    );
}
export default Articles;
```

Comment: Ahora ya pasó los 50k, ya paso esto 3 vezes, para que no pase es solo no acceder la página, pero entonces que tiene de malo el codigo?.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes lo siguiente:

```javascript
const articlesCollectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');
```

Esto significa que en cada refresco de tu componente estás pidiendo esa información a firebase.

Por algún motivo tu componente debe refrescarse muy a menudo, creando una nueva petición a firebase.

Peor aún, aunque la llamada a `collection` devuelva los mismos datos, es muy probable que el objeto `articlesCollectionRef` no sea la misma instancia, con lo que la llamada a `useEffect` posiblemente se esté ejecutando también para cada refresco. Puedes probar a monitorizar añadiendo algunos `console.log` en tu componente para comprobarlo.